# Laravel Route resource does not delete table data?

Tags: php, laravel-5

working with Laravel 5.6 and Mysql. and need delete table data using following data.

```
<td><a class="button is-outlined" href="/student/{{$student->id}}/delete">Delete</a></td>
```

and Controller delete function is,

```
public function delete($id)
    {
         DB::table('students')
            ->where('id', $id)

            ->delete();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

and route is like this,

```
Route::resource('student','StudentController');
```

but when click delete button it is generated following error message,
`(1/1) NotFoundHttpException`

how can fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

If you use resource controller, you can't generate a link for the **DELETE** method.

By the way, it's not `delete` method, but `destroy` method and link.

The **DELETE** method expects the request to have **DELETE** header (like POST, GET or PUT).

The simplest way is to define an URL for you `delete` method :

```
Route::get('student/{site}/delete', ['as' => 'student.delete', 'uses' => 'StudentController@delete']);
```

Or you must use a form like this to call **DELETE** header :

```
<form action="{{ route('student.destroy', $studentId) }}" method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
    <button>Delete</button>
</form>
```

And you need to change the name of your method :

```
public function destroy($id)
```

Comment: I think the form is more elegant way to do it.

Comment: use your form way but got this error msg here `Route [student.delete] not defined`

Comment: I updated my answer 8 minutes ago, it's not `delete` but `destroy` you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Resource Controller you can try this. You can try to DELETE using AJAX Call too.

```
<td><a class="button is-outlined" id="delete-record">Delete</a></td>
```

`DELETE` verb will automatically call `destroy` action from your `Resource Controller`.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $deleted = DB::table('students')
                 ->where('id', $id)
                 ->delete();
    // return number of deleted records             
    return $deleted;
}
```

And to perform DELETE use AJAX call like this.

```
$('#delete-record').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: '/student/'+{{$student->id}},
        type: 'DELETE',  // user.destroy
        success: function(result) {
            console.log("Success");
            console.log("No. Of Deleted Records = "+result);
        }
        });
});
```

I hope this solution will also work like above one that is already provided.